# Why does one of my fields have "@" in front of its name in debug?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a class with a local variable called "group", as you can see I give it a value in the constructor (the value I assign it is `null` if it matters):

[image]

The strange thing is, when I debug my project, the name "group" suddenly becomes "@group":

[image]

I don't have this for any other variables, is this something of Visual Studio 2015? Never saw this before in earlier versions. If it's not a bug, what does it mean?

**Edit:** "@group" and "group" can both be used in code:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "group" is a keyword, as used in LINQ:

```
  var x = from y in collection
          group y by p.name into g ....
```

In C# keywords can be uses as names, if they are  prefixed by `@` and used like this:

```
var @class = "car";
```

Comment: Thanks, for the quick respons!

Comment: I didn't have to use the '@' to define the name though, that's why I didn't know where it came from.

Comment: It's a new feature, it seems. Declaring `var x = new { group = 10, where = 20, test = 30 };` causes the debugger to show @group = 10, test = 20, @where = 30. I find it rather nice.

Comment: Yes it's nice, but a bit confusing if you don't know where it comes from :) Keywords like `where` and `class` would ring a bell for me, but I didn't think about Linq `group` keyword